# Viber: The webhook URL is not valid

Tags: viber

Сменилась сервер бота.
При выполнении запроса POST на https://chatapi.viber.com/pa/set_webhook получаю ошибку: 1   invalidUrl  The webhook URL is not valid
Где именно разбирать или искать проблему? В какой части кода?

Comment: какие данные вы посылаете в POST-запросе?

Comment: {
   "url":"https://site.com/www/webhook/viber/",
   "event_types":[
      "message",
      "conversation_started"
   ],
   "auth_token":"(тут токен)",
   "send_name":true,
   "send_photo":true
}

Comment: а можете добавить в вопрос в виде кода? комментарий съел, например, протокол в url

Comment: `{
   "url":"https://site.com/www/webhook/viber/",
   "event_types":[
      "message",
      "conversation_started"
   ],
   "auth_token":"тут_токен",
   "send_name":true,
   "send_photo":true
}`